# Laravel model observer method doesn't get fired

Tags: laravel, updating, observers

In my Laravel (7.x) I am trying to use `Observers` for updating `device_inventories` table if the value of the record if the record of the `subscriber_devices` table is updated as `inactive`.

```
device_inventories         |    subscriber_devices
-----------------------    |    --------------------------------
# | title    | status      |    # | device_inventory_id | status
-----------------------    |    --------------------------------
1 | device-1 | active      |    1 |                   1 | active
2 | device-2 | active      |    2 |                   2 | active
```

For example:
Suppose I update the record `id = 2` of `subscriber_devices` to `status = inactive` then the value of `device_inventories / status` should be updated to `replacement`. Assuming, that the device was damaged and needs to be sent for replacement.

AppServiceProvider.php

```php
use App\SubscriberDevice;
use App\Observers\ObserverChangeDeviceInventoryStatusToReplacement;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
   public function boot()
   {
     SubscriberDevice::observe(ObserverChangeDeviceInventoryStatusToReplacement::class);
   }
}
```

App\Observers\ObserverChangeDeviceInventoryStatusToReplacement.php

```php
use App\DeviceInventory;
use App\SubscriberDevice;

class ObserverChangeDeviceInventoryStatusToReplacement
{
   public function updated(SubscriberDevice $SubscriberDevice)
   {
      DeviceInventory::where('id', $SubscriberDevice->device_inventory_id)->update([
         'status' => 'replacement'
      ]);
   }
}
```

App\SubscriberDevice.php

```php
class SubscriberDevice extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'subscriber_devices';

   public function _status($token, $reason)
   {
      self::where('token', $token)->update([
         'reason' => $reason,
         'status' => 'inactive',
      ]);
   }
}
```

The observer method doesn't seems to be firing. What am I doing wrong.?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41295032/laravel-eloquent-model-update-event-is-not-fired)

Comment: Thanks @EmptyBrain, It worked. I'll post my working code. Thanks again... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @EmptyBrain.

App\SubscriberDevice.php

```php
class SubscriberDevice extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'subscriber_devices';

   public function _status($token, $reason)
   {
      $self = self::where('token', $token)->first();

      $self->update([
         'reason' => $reason,
         'status' => 'inactive',
      ]);
   }
}
```

Reference [laravel Eloquent model update event is not fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41295032/laravel-eloquent-model-update-event-is-not-fired)